# What's the best way to request API

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currenlty using "direct api calls" and I have a daily limit of 5k. If the user refreshes the app 5 times, that's 5 api calls. So It's a LOT.

What can I do to stop that? I was thinking in get the API Json's download it and then parse my downloaded JSON.
But the problem is that the JSON updates every 24 hours(and occasionally in 6 hours).

This package does the job?
https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage

If yes, can someone explaint It to me, or
forward me to some articles?

Thank you.

Comment: You can also use the Shared preferences plugin for caching the data.

Comment: Oh nice, but how does this works? Do i need to change all my code ?

Comment: If you are using shared preferences, local storage plugin is not required you can save the entire response from the API as a  string. check the below link
https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127